# Using AndroidAsync in my project

Tags: android, androidasync-koush

I'm following a tutorial where they want me to use [android websockets library](https://github.com/koush/android-websockets), unfortunately this library is deprecated and I should now use [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync).

This should be an easy task for the common Android Developer, but I'm kinda new to Android Development so I would like some help doing this.

I have posted my code as a pastebin because the code is too big to post here.

My code:
http://pastebin.com/dYNAG6eX

The library is already imported into the project, I just need some help changing the code to the correct things.

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @nandsito For starters the class `WebSocketClient` is not used anymore, or at least I couldn't find it. So pretty much I need some help figuring out a replacement for this one

Comment: read through the library documentation and browse the examples, it is the piece of advice i can give you. After that, if you face a specific issue, ask a question about it. Broad questions have less chance of being addressed

Comment: @nandsito I can't really seem to find a way to match the new library to my code. There are a lot of differences and I do not really understand what to change and what not

Comment: if the two libraries are much different from each other, you will have to *understand* how the old code works, *understand* how to use the new library and start a new implementation from scratch